# Matching a page-scoped ID and a chatbot-scoped ID: several questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have a web site (gigsnet) with a Facebook login. I did it using Passport/oauth.
I want to implement a chatbot, so that our users can chat to the "Gigsnet" page, and get personalised responses from the chatbot.

I realise that the IDs won't match, and that some "magic" is necessary here. So, here we go.

## SOME IDS

This is what my server receives when a message by myself (page admin) arrives:

```
Requested:  /app/chatbot
REQUEST BODY: { object: 'page',
  entry: 
   [ { id: '1130858117040228',
       time: 1495584613258,
       messaging: 
        [ { sender: { id: '119XXXXXX7137093' },
            recipient: { id: '1130858117040228' },
            timestamp: 1495584613013,
            message: 
             { mid: 'mid.$cAAQEgkm16DpiaQ9qlVcN8ohagocY',
               seq: 290123,
               text: 'd' } } ] } ] }
POST /app/chatbot 200 1.581 ms - -
```

This tells me that my user ID for the chatbot is 119XXXXXX7137093.
Also, this is what I have on my DB for authenticated users:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5924c947b0d5a1095c8f326c"), "strategyId" : "facebook", "field1" : "636379230", "field3" : "EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAFuHIC4U9CxB8vEFcL25iQ6vsVkT9s1CKfJtqPPg6YhJjZAepu2v6EqtOjj6UDCaTYxca9UbRReIhKeIu4UGmEW4L9lJcGDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXl4YgoMx8ExmI0zZCEsbZBYtZA9SR3PW9FkMdZCkgZD", "userId" : ObjectId("59239720a04b2e1de8e103d8"), "id" : ObjectId("5924c947b0d5a1095c8f326b"), "_children" : {  }, "_clean" : true }
```

This particular user happens to be admin of the pages, the app, and owner of the company that owns page and app.

So:

- USER ID (CHATBOT SCOPE): 119XXXXXX7137093
- USER ID (LOGIN APP SCOPE): 636379230 WITH ADMIN ACCESS TOKEN: EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAFuHIC4U9CxB8vEFcL25iQ6vsVkT9s1CKfJtqPPg6YhJjZAepu2v6EqtOjj6UDCaTYxca9UbRReIhKeIu4UGmEW4L9lJcGDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXl4YgoMx8ExmI0zZCEsbZBYtZA9SR3PW9FkMdZCkgZD
  PAGE ID: gigsnetco
- APP ID (LOGIN APP): 453817548028633

The access token is important as I am the admin for the pages.

## USER ID IN MESSENGER BOT -> USER ID IN LOGIN APP (with extra step)

To make this call, I need FIRST an access token for the page. So, here I am using my user's oauth access token from the database in order to get another access token, the one to administer pages.

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/gigsnetco?access_token=EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAFuHIC4U9CxB8vEFcL25iQ6vsVkT9s1CKfJtqPPg6YhJjZAepu2v6EqtOjj6UDCaTYxca9UbRReIhKeIu4UGmEW4L9lJcGDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXl4YgoMx8ExmI0zZCEsbZBYtZA9SR3PW9FkMdZCkgZD&fields=access_token"
```

{"access_token":"EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAMeNZAE09EsRndMYvDlVpNeE6HT05zxqeL2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDs2vdiSYlErrdw8ZAF3uBdUiIjnioXxohljA3mLjlKbgFZC5tfz7ivGHCHb4LubXHBNx7wLMMLcl7WrZC627uca2HW18dQZBH5MGhOqvHRyYXQZDZD","id":"1130858117040228"}

I now use the token for the page ID above to make a request on the user 119XXXXXX7137093 (chatbot) asking it the list of ids for linked pages.
Note: I am using the user id 119XXXXXX7137093, filtering by app ID, using the page's access token.

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/119XXXXXX7137093/ids_for_apps?app=453817548028633&access_token=EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAMeNZAE09EsRndMYvDlVpNeE6HT05zxqeL2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDs2vdiSYlErrdw8ZAF3uBdUiIjnioXxohljA3mLjlKbgFZC5tfz7ivGHCHb4LubXHBNx7wLMMLcl7WrZC627uca2HW18dQZBH5MGhOqvHRyYXQZDZD"

{"data":[{"id":"636379230","app":{"link":"http:\/\/www.gigsnet.com\/","name":"Login","id":"453817548028633"}}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"NDUzODE3NTQ4MDI4NjMz","after":"NDUzODE3NTQ4MDI4NjMz"}}}
```

Bingo! I have 636379230. When a user types anything to the chatbot, I can now cross-reference them with a user who has previously logged in, and provide personalised information.

## USER ID IN LOGIN ALL -> USER ID IN MESSENGER

Here I am using the access token from the screen https://developers.facebook.com/apps/453817548028633/messenger/ in "Token generation".

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/636379230/ids_for_apps?app=453817548028633&access_token=EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAKycZAeDI4D13sOVZAZAlNJqZCTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxsyaOs9WgQO2jcnHJeEYAbUlEdCU1xejYjTlWE1w4tEfe7IZAAw8i3X2qn1AKwDlHhwHbQsoylxPZAcPagVKemSd6KQwUP2gB8pkm61PumqLiVuIw3B3lQZDZD"

{"data":[{"id":"636379230","app":{"link":"http:\/\/www.gigsnet.com\/","name":"Login","id":"453817548028633"}}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"NDUzODE3NTQ4MDI4NjMz","after":"NDUzODE3NTQ4MDI4NjMz"}}}
```

Note that my own access token (I guess because I am the page admin) ALSO works:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/636379230/ids_for_apps?app=453817548028633&access_token=EAAGcvqGZBOtkBAFuHIC4U9CxB8vEFcL25iQ6vsVkT9s1CKfJtqPPg6YhJjZAepu2v6EqtOjj6UDCaTYxca9UbRReIhKeIu4UGmEW4L9lJcGDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXl4YgoMx8ExmI0zZCEsbZBYtZA9SR3PW9FkMdZCkgZD"

{"data":[{"id":"636379230","app":{"link":"http:\/\/www.gigsnet.com\/","name":"Login","id":"453817548028633"}}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"NDUzODE3NTQ4MDI4NjMz","after":"NDUzODE3NTQ4MDI4NjMz"}}}
```

Bingo! 636379230 is the user ID for messenger.

## QUESTIONS

- The API documentation mentions that I should provide appsecret_proof in order to get ids_for_pages to work. However, I didn't have to (plus, you only provide a PHP example, and I couldn't find an example in node). Is it OK not to provide appsecret_proof?
- In order to make calls, I am using my own access token (as the page admin); I obtained this access token using oauth, using my app (I am using passport on nodejs).

  - Will this token expire after 60 days?
  - If so, does that mean that I ought to link/unlink my account so that I generate a new access token? (Or, use an API command to get a new access token? (If so, which one?)
  - Since the access token expires, shall I keep on refreshing it for logged in users as well? The problem is that once a user is logged in, they are alogged in.
- Does the page access token also expire? How often shall I re-generate it? Surely, regenerate it for every received message would be wasteful on my end and your end...!
- Are scoped IDs stable? Do I absolutely know that the IDs will never change? Once I make the connection, can I save it and have it like that forever? Even if a user unlinks themselves with oauth and then link themselves back? Or in case the access tokens expire for example. If they do change, how do I know if they are expired/?

Thank you!

Comment: For all the token-related questions, please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens